# Are there any homebrew games (or demos) for the Timex/Sinclair 2068?

Tags: software, homemade, timex-sinclair

I know there has long been a thriving homebrew scene for games and demos for the original Sinclair Spectrum range and also for the Russian and Eastern Bloc Spectrum clones.

But I expected some old Speccy people could be curious about the American offshoot of the Spectrum, the Timex 2068 and 2048, especially since they have two extra graphics modes.

I've looked on the Speccy download sites I know about and I've done a fair bit of Googling and so far I haven't found anything. But maybe it's out there and I'm missing it?

Or maybe the homebrew type people work just to their personal nostalgia and/or specifically target the real hardware they own rather than emulators. I'm sure genuine Timex/Sinclairs are not commonly owned by Speccy enthusiasts in the UK and Europe.

I would be happy to find a single homebrew game or demo made in the last decade or two that targets the Timex machines' extra features.

---

Actually I don't even know which file formats are used by Timex emulators. The one I downloaded kept crashing. I know cartridge images use filenames ending with `.dck` and those could be used for homebrew in emulators if not so easily in real hardware.

Comment: As I recall there also was a Timex Sinclair 2048. But I don't know what the difference is between that and a 2068.

Comment: Crap. I have a Sinclair around here in a box out in the shed. Problem is.. it's 1200 sq ft in size, 25' ceiling, with lots of shelving everywhere to hold 50 years of accumulation. (There are, for example, 6 old new-in-box Tektronix 2465B scope tubes out there, too.) One of these days.... ;)

Comment: Are you aware of [pouët.net](https://www.pouet.net/)? You did not post any URL of sites you visited... (Disclaimer: I did not try to find something there.)

Comment: @OmarL: Yes I wasn't sure whether to include that because I also couldn't remember the difference and it was very late. There are two kinds of 2068 too IIRC.

Comment: @thebusybee No I never came across that one. I'm not sure what snapshot or tape image file formats are used for the Timex machines but cartridges use `.dck` which I suppose could be used for homebrew at least on emulators.

Comment: @thebusybee I found this on that site. I'm not sure it qualifies as the comments say it runs on a real Spectrum. The comments also say it's basic. If that means it's programmed in basic then I wouldn't count it. It has no graphic effects. https://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=54899

Comment: Another one on that site claims to be for the 2048/2068 using its modes. But in the YT video I don't see the extra modes and it starts with a `LOAD` command on a screen with just the Sinclair copyright, not the Timex one. https://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=64102#c703690

Comment: At least _something_, but you're right. BASIC and running on a plain Speccy. :-D Too bad that I have to work for a living, retirement is still some years away. I made few ZX81 demos, since the challenge is more interesting if the machine is more limited. I'm thinking to step back to the ZX80.

Answer (score 3):

I present here the first World Museum about the ZX Spectrum, with many information about the Timex clones:

- https://loadzx.com/en/
- https://www.facebook.com/LoadZXSpectrum/

Another info:

1 - The TC2048 never haded seen live in USA market. But in Portugal (Europe) is very popular. The 2068 have two versions, one TC2068 to system Pal (Portugal) and other TS2068 for the NTSC (USA). The size of the cartridges slot is different between the two too.
More details about the differences: https://www.liquisearch.com/timex_sinclair_2068/differences_between_ts2068_tc2068_and_uk2086

2 - Visit the https://planetasinclair.blogspot.com/ (please contact the owner of this blog)

3 - If you have Facebook profile, i strong suggest this group [PT]: https://www.facebook.com/groups/126122660738357
(note exist another UK ans ES groups, i will add here later)

4 - Video about the History of TIMEX factory in Portugal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8pVcfWmmjo&t=18s

5 - Video about TC2068:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeTa60_eafc

6 - Timex Sinclair TS2068 Computer S-Video Expansion Card - Quality video from Timex Speccy Computer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOxoXiHxIc0

7 - Timex Sinclair 2068 Computer Unboxing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTsTdPh7ZJU

8 - TS2068 EPROM Command Cartridge:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYMBuVz32ZE

9 - Timmy - demo for Timex Computer 2048 / 2068 by speccy.pl:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwIgyTzJdaY

10 - ZX Spectrum USA Edition - The Timex Sinclair TS2068 Review, Teardown and Comparison !!:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXYQByqQesI

11 - Spectrum viaja a USA: Timex Sinclair 2068 junto a Dario Ruellan:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng4en24dMWM

12 - Timex Sinclair 2068 - The American ZX Spectrum:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTKckoSj-OE&t=644s

13 - Timex 2048 e Match Point - Paraíso Filmes (RTP - 2002):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBjrs0tlsxk

14 - Timex/Sinclair TS2068 Parte 1/3:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fakjW0hFWhY

15 - Timex/Sinclair TS2068 - Aplicaciones Parte 2/3:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OA2pPGPEuwM

16 - Timex/Sinclair TS2068 - Juegos Parte 3/3:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT9GZEkC2PI

17 - Interlace Demo running on real NTSC Timex Sinclair 2068 Computer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNcvt8GDhIk

18 - Cartridge Timex Sinclair 2068 Demo ZX ROM Spectrum Emulator and Pole Position Game:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JByrzgxnWw

19 - Timex 2068 + FDD3000 playing STC music:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5RP79jwYrs

20 - Timex Sinclair 2068:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2LNYI2VHGE

21 - Timex Sinclair TS2068 & Califone 3670 Cassette Deck:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkFehezoAnE

Comment: Great links. Still, it might be helpful to add some of that information here. Not everyone wants to use Facebook and even less may speak Portuguese.

Comment: "and other for the Secam (USA)"... but the USA uses NTSC. Secam was French.

Comment: I watched the "Timmy" demo and couldn't see anything in it that looked like it was using 2048/2068 features. Did I miss something. I'll start watching all the other videos. I've seen some already.

Comment: At fist I thought "Crazy Bugs" looked like it was running in a Timex hi-res screen mode, but even it turns out to just be a plain Speccy game I wasn't familiar with.

Comment: @hippietrail I think you can see 8x1 color mode in Timmy and 512x192 hi-res graphics. Have a second look perhaps.

Comment: @dotz Ah yes, the only part that looks like it is 512x192 is at about 34 seconds in with the big "Timmy" graphic and the "wavy" text below. As the graphics is drawn you can see the vertical bars since the second half of screen memory in that mode is every second column. Also if you zoom in you can see the pixels are vertical 1x2 bricks. Everywhere else in the demo the pixels are square. I've actually forgotten what to look for in the 8x1 color mode since this effect can be done on regular Speccys but surely with certain limitations. I'm not sure I should accept this whole answer though.

Comment: @hippietrail by this time we should have a graphics library for TS 2048/2068 coded in ZX Basic perhaps, do you know any?